# Pegar Link da categoria de produtos e exibir uma lista com as sub-categorias do produto do woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Eu uso esse código para exibir uma lista das sub categorias dos posts Wordpress, queria saber como eu faço para ao invés de pegar a categoria dos posts eu pegar a categoria dos produtos do Woocommerce.

```
        <!-- CATEGORIA -->
    <?php $id_da_categoria = get_cat_id('nome da categoria'); 
    $link_da_categoria = get_category_link($id_da_categoria); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $link_da_categoria ;?>"> CATEGORIA </a>

    <ul>
        <!-- Exibe as sub categorias em uma lista -->
        <?php
        $id_da_categoria = get_cat_id('categoria');
        wp_list_categories('sort_column=name&child_of='."$id_da_categoria".'&title_li=');
        ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

É possível listar as categorias usando a função `get_categories()`, e passar o parâmetro `taxonomy` como `product_cat`.

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php

  $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
  $orderby      = 'name';

  $args = array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'orderby' => $orderby);

  $product_categories = get_categories( $args );

?>
```

Comment: Obrigado Fellipe Sores mas não consegui, sou iniciante e não edento nada de PHP.

Comment: Na verdade o que eu quero é cria um link para ao clicar entrar na pagina de categoria e logo abaixo desse link uma lista exibindo todas as sub categorias. Não sei se estou sendo claro peço desculpa se não deixei clara a minha dúvida.